# When paint with stencil decal gets bad quality

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

[image: Example]

Blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qOShk5-Qa61Y3lZghscwfCi7ogJxM3vu/view?usp=sharing

Textures: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12TesRIClLJIZXKfPR-qHR_8AdhQNv5SI?usp=sharing

P.S I tried to upscale the decal but it didnt help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The destination texture resolution where the paint is scaled to is the problem - the area being painted represents too few pixels compared to the source stencil image, so the edges are going to be lower resolution and jagged. The solution is a better UV unwrap that gives more pixels to the desired paint areas BEFORE painting the stencil into the target texture image.